# aws sagemaker giving The model data archive is too large. Please reduce the size of the model data archive

Tags: training-data, amazon-sagemaker

I am using aws sagemaker to deploy a model whose generated artifacts are huge. The compressed size is about 80GB. Deploying on sage maker on a ml.m5.12xlarge instance is throwing this error while deploying to the endpoint
 `The model data archive is too large. Please reduce the size of the model data archive or move to an instance type with more memory.`

I found that aws attaches EBS volume based on instance size(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/host-instance-storage.html)  and i couldnot find anything more that 30Gb here. Should i go with a multi model endpoint here?

Comment: what model has such a big artifact? this is quite rare; maybe there is a way to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

"d" instances have bigger (NVMe) volumes; you can try deploying to `ml.m5d.*` for example. But keep in mind that your download and instantiation time may exceed the service limits (between 15-20min in my experience) so if you can't have an endpoint up in that timeframe you may still encounter an error.